How to pass an output variable value from one template into another template parameter in a different job
I want to capitalize on using reusable templates. I have the following parent pipeline:
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: Configuration/cfgTemplates

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- job: ResolveId
  displayName: Resolve ID
  steps:
  - template: /tasks/get_id.yml@templates
    parameters:
      name: test

- job: SetId
  dependsOn: ResolveId
  variables:
    resolvedId: $[ dependencies.ResolveId.outputs['getid.id'] ]
  steps:
    - script: |
        echo Retrieved id: $(resolvedId)

- template: child.yml
  parameters:
    dependsOn: SetId
    id: $(resolvedId)


Here is the get_id.yml pipeline template:
parameters:
- name: name
  type: string
- name: showAdditionalOutput
  type: boolean
  default: false

steps:
- script: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=id;isOutput=true]${{ parameters.name }}:342c2d35-1ded-438a-971f-a7540f7220d9"
  displayName: Get ID
  name: getid

- script: |
    echo Id = $(getid.id)
  enabled: ${{ parameters.showAdditionalOutput }}

Here is the child.yml pipeline template:
parameters:
  - name: id
  - name: dependsOn
    type: object
    default: []  

jobs:
- job: validate_id
  displayName: ID Validation
  dependsOn: ${{ parameters.dependsOn }}
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo ${{ parameters.id }}

Here is the output:
Sample output for above
I know I can get access to the output variable in the SetId step:
Output value from SetId
I tried several various ways based on articles/Stack overflow posts but cannot get the value resolved in the child.yml template. What am I doing wrong. I realize that I'm trying to pass a runtime variable into another template. Based on examples floating around, this should work, right?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried various variable formats, like the following:
- template: child.yml
  parameters:
    dependsOn: SetId
    id: $[ dependencies.ResolveId.outputs['getid.id'] ]


Hi @mremkiewicz, Welcome to SO. We should not use compile time expression ${{ parameters.id }} to echo output variable value that is generated during runtime. I will share a working sample in the answer shortly.

Hi @mremkiewicz, Have you got a chance to check my answer below to use different variable syntax? Hope the information may help resolve your concerns. Thx and have a great day.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT Thank you! Sorry for the delay. This was what I was missing.

Based on the requirement to generate output variable during runtime and pass it to downstream job in template, we should not echo template expression ${{ parameters.id }} in script directly, as such expressions are processed at compile time, while we can define a new variable on job level with the value of ${{ parameters.id }} that is passed into template.
Besides, the reason that ${{ parameters.test }} was working when being passed in template /tasks/get_id.yml@templates was ${{ parameters.test }} had the static value of test at compile time; however, ${{ parameters.id }} didn't have an expanded value at compile time. See the document to help us Understand variable syntax.
In addition, since we expect to retrieve the output variable generated from upstream job: ResolveId, we need to set ResolveId as the dependency of job: validate_id. It is highly suggested we echo the dependencies information in the downstream job for troubleshooting. Here is the YAML definitions of my working pipeline for your reference.
parent.yml
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: Configuration/cfgTemplates

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- job: ResolveId
  displayName: Resolve ID
  steps:
  - template: /tasks/get_id.yml@templates
    parameters:
      name: test

- job: SetId
  dependsOn: ResolveId
  variables:
    resolvedId: $[ dependencies.ResolveId.outputs['getid.id'] ]
  steps:
    - script: |
        echo Retrieved id: $(resolvedId)

- template: child.yml
  parameters:
    dependsOn: [ResolveId, SetId]
    id: $[ dependencies.ResolveId.outputs['getid.id'] ]


child.yml
parameters:
  - name: id
  - name: dependsOn
    type: object
    default: []  

jobs:
- job: validate_id
  displayName: ID Validation
  dependsOn: ${{ parameters.dependsOn }}
  variables:
    TemplateId: ${{ parameters.id }}
    deps: $[convertToJson(dependencies)]
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo Validate id in template: $(TemplateId)
      echo "$(deps)"



